# Get an array index from a list of parameters in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want a method or function to obtain elements of an array using an array of indices in Java, but I'm not sure how to do this yet. Is it possible to obtain an array index from an array of parameter in Java (so that `getArrayIndex(theArray, [0, 1])` would return `theArray[0][1]`?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Object[][] theArray = {{"Hi!"}, {"Hi!"}, {"Hi!", "Hi!"}};
        Object index1 = getArrayIndex(theArray, [0, 0]) //this should return theArray[0][0]
        Object[] index1 = getArrayIndex(theArray, [0]) //this should return theArray[0]
    }

    public static Object getArrayIndex(Object[] theArray, Object[] theIndices){
        //get the object at the specified indices
    }
}
```

Comment: System.arraycopy(java.lang.Object, int, java.lang.Object, int, int) should help.

Comment: I assume you want the signature to be `public static Object getArrayIndex(Object[][] theArray, Object[] theIndices) {` (or even better, `public static Object getArrayIndex(Object[][] theArray, int[] theIndices) {`) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Object getArrayIndex(Object[] theArray, Integer[] theIndices){
    Object result=theArray;
    for(Integer index: theIndices) {
        result = ((Object[])result)[index];
    }    
    return result;        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this (and other solutions) do no bounds checking, so you could get an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

```
// returns the Object at the specified indices
public static Object getArrayIndex(Object[][] theArray, int[] theIndices) {
   if (theIndices.length > 1) {
     return theArray[theIndices[0]][theIndices[1]];
   }
   return theArray[theIndices[0]];
}
```